# discord.py running with this message but, command not working

Tags: python, discord

**learn.py**

```
import asyncio
import datetime
import discord
import openpyxl    

client = discord.Client(command_prefix='?',intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.content.startswith("learn"):
        word = message.content.split(" ")
        word_ = message.content.replace("learn ", "").replace(word[1], "")
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("memory.xlsx")
        ws = wb.active

        for i in range(1, 10):
            if wb["A" + str(i)].value == "." or ws["A" + str(i)].value == word[1]:
                wb["A" + str(i)].value = word[1]
                wb["B" + str(i)].value = word_
                await message.channel.send("adding success.")
                break
        ws.save("memory.xlsx")
        await message.send(message)
```

these are the error, right down below

↓

?[30;1m2022-07-10 12:08:12?[0m ?[34;1mINFO    ?[0m ?[35mdiscord.gateway?[0m Shard ID None has sent the IDENTIFY payload.
?[30;1m2022-07-10 12:08:12?[0m ?[34;1mINFO    ?[0m ?[35mdiscord.gateway?[0m Shard ID None has connected
to Gateway (Session ID: cdc97a8a298cb316248b9995fbbb2cdc).

it's running but with this message and no command working, i tried to figure it out, but have no idea where to fix. if anyone could help me, will be really grateful. have a nice day!

Comment: You mixed the functionality of `discord.Client` and `discord.ext.commands.Bot`. I would recommend read docs. Your command should be functional without your intended prefix `?`

Comment: appreciate it! just fixed it, but still doesn't work with the same result.